# mongoose automatically detect primary

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

Does mongoose automatically detects PRIMARY in a replica set even when it's changed?

I'm pretty sure that's the case but I have to make sure b/c I can't find anything related to that in the docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose underneath just uses the [mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) native nodejs driver to establish a connection. You should pass in your connection string to mongoose (which is then passed to mongodb's native node driver) *all* IP addresses in the replica set, so that it can switch to the new primary in the case of failover.

Format of the connection string from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/connection-string/)

> `mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]`

Comment: So it automatically switching to the new primary? Where do you see it documented?